# Why are my bulleted lines automatically joining?

Tags: formatting, options, filetype-markdown, join

I use the `a` formatoption to make my text hard wrap, and the `n` formatoption to recognize numbered lists.  The help says that the `n` option should use the `formatlistpat` regex to determine which lines not to mess with, but it doesn't seem to be working for me; vim is joining all my bulleted lines.

These are the values of my options:

```
formatoptions=tqlran
textwidth=65
formatlistpat=^\s*\d\+\.\s\+\|^[-*+]\s\+\|^\[^\ze[^\]]\+\]:
filetype=markdown
```

Also, formatlistpat was "Last set from usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1650_1/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/markdown.vim", so I know it's not just a matter of me not escaping the regex correctly when setting it.

An example of the bad behavior can be seen [in this video](https://asciinema.org/a/KsfGZNBI48MNaAWhUmm1UV2dy?t=4).

Any idea how I can make vim stop joining lines like this?

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose set comments?` Does the command `:set comments&` fix the issue?

Comment: And how about `:set comments+=fb:-` ?

Comment: Hi @Rich, thanks so much for your response! I wasn't aware of the comments functionality and reading the help for it has helped me a ton and fixed the joining problem.  However, I'm still having a strange issue where new lines get an increased level of indentation, and I can't figure out why, since the help pages say the 'f' option for comments "preserves indentation".  Would you happen to have any idea what could be going on here? I made a short video to show the behavior and my settings: https://asciinema.org/a/nd8icEv0Bkaphkhvf7qKAyqiq . Thanks again!